# IBM Cognos 11...Using Conditional Block with variable to select a Date Selector Type in a drop down on a prompt page

Tags: conditional-statements, block, cognos-11

I have the Prompt page working in Page Design, I have a Block variable and a "Current Block" setting for each of 3 selection possibilities, if the customer wants to only select entire Fiscal Years, a checkbox selector for those years shows, if by Fiscal Year-months (variable)...The FY checkbox selector with the FY-Month checkbox selector pops up, and using the Date Selectors for Start and End dates, that also pops up with the right variable value in the parameter selected.  My problem is with the Conditional Block, and the dropdown to select the variable value...when I go to run the report, a pre-prompt for my Start and End date parameters and the Date Selector Type parameter for the 3 conditions comes up, and whichever one I select, it displays on the prompt page in the conditional block and pre-populates the dropdown above it, but my Date-Type Selector Value Prompt on the Prompt Page, when changing the option in that dropdown, does not change the Control Block's Current Block value through the vDateSelector variable, although it uses the correct variable, and the Block Variable is the same one for those 3 values.  How do you get the dropdown value-change to actually change the Conditional Block to display each different Date Selector Type based on the condition selected?

It's hard, because I feel like I've tried everything, but I'm clueless, once the pre prompt-page prompt is selected, it selects the objects in the Block that will display, but when the prompt page shows up, the value pre-selected shows in the dropdown with the correct object displaying, but the dropdown, if changed won't change the object that is visible.

Comment: Can you share screen shots of the prompt page and page?

Comment: I cannot, it's on a restricted website...but your answer below looks great, I'll try it when I can work on that report later!  Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hi WendellFry and welcome

1. As a suggestion, instead of using a conditional block, you may want to try a render variable to hide/show what you want.  That might be a little easier to manage

For example a value prompt with static choices
[image]

i.e.

[image]

For the variable, string should be fine
The expression would be something like this..
ParamValue('YourParameter')

Then use the + sign to add what values are valid

[image]

2. Add a button and set the property to reprompt so the screen can refresh and update how you want to render your prompts
   You can also set your value prompt to autosubmit (so your user will not have to select the reprompt)

This will get what I believe you want, for the dropdown value to change what is displayed

Comment: Following up, did it work?

Comment: That looks really good, VAI Jason!  I will have to try that when I get a chance...Thank you sooo much!  Awesome! keep running into new things to solve and that report is on hold, right now, but I can see that it will work...will let you know...!